# Local code is not in sync with Remote Repository

Tags: git, bitbucket

We are facing the below issue, where our local code is not in sync with Remote Repository.

We have recently pushed a code (which is not maintained in Git Earlier) to Git Repository.After pushing the local copy to Git Repository we realized, that we have some updated local copy in another path in our local machine and we are not trying to push these things to Remote Repository. While Pushing the changes we are hitting into below issue.

```
$ git push origin master
To https://vcs.jd-staging.com/bitbucket/scm/bmsg/bmsg.git
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://vcs.jd-staging.com/bitbucket/scm/bmsg/bmsg.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because a pushed branch tip is behind its remote
hint: counterpart. Check out this branch and integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g. 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.


$ git branch -r
  origin/master

$ git pull origin master
From https://vcs.jd-staging.com/bitbucket/scm/bmsg/bmsg
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
Already up to date.

$ git push origin master
To https://vcs.jd-staging.com/bitbucket/scm/bmsg/bmsg.git
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://vcs.jd-staging.com/bitbucket/scm/bmsg/bmsg.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because a pushed branch tip is behind its remote
hint: counterpart. Check out this branch and integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g. 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.

$ git pull --rebase origin master
From https://vcs.jd-staging.com/bitbucket/scm/bmsg/bmsg
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
Already up to date.
fatal: It seems that there is already a rebase-apply directory, and
I wonder if you are in the middle of another rebase.  If that is the
case, please try
        git rebase (--continue | --abort | --skip)
If that is not the case, please
        rm -fr ".git/rebase-apply"
and run me again.  I am stopping in case you still have something valuable there.

$ git pull origin master
From https://vcs.jd-staging.com/bitbucket/scm/bmsg/bmsg
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
fatal: refusing to merge unrelated histories
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely a simple `git pull` would resolve this issue:

```
# from master
git pull origin master
```

But note that this may result in merge conflicts locally, which you would have to resolve (followed by a `git commit`).  Another option here would be to pull using a rebase strategy:

```
git pull --rebase origin master
```

This would preserve your local commits, though it could still result in merge conflicts happening.

**Edit:**

The error message `refusing to merge unrelated histories` means that your local repo is not the same as the remote repo.  That is, your local repository contains some project other than what is in the remote to which you are pointing.  This could happen because the remote history were changed, or because you configured wrongly locally.

Comment: Tried that already but it doesn't seem to work. Updated the result in the Question.

Comment: `fatal: It seems that there is already a rebase-apply directory` <-- there is some problem here.  Try doing `git rebase --abort` first, then just `git pull origin master`.

Comment: After the abort command, I have tried git pull again, but it says "refusing to merge" error message. Updated the same in Question. Any thoughts?

Comment: OK, now we're making progress.  Type `git status` and see which files are in conflict.  You will have to resolve the merge conflicts.  Look for `<<<<<<<` ... `=======` ... `>>>>>>>` markers in your files.

Comment: git status shows "nothing to commit, working tree clean"

Comment: Check my edit.  You have some serious problems with your configuration.  Keep in mind that you can't just point a different repo to a remote and expect to be able to pull and push.

Comment: Understood, but this is the scenario.. We had two local copies... Local copy (1) with around 100 files.. Local copy (2) with around 100+ files (same files from Local Copy-1 with some changes and some additional files).. We have pushed local copy (1) to remote repository and then realized local copy (2) is the updated one.. So trying to push local copy (2) to the same remote repos. Is that not possible?

Comment: No, that's not generally possible if the histories are not related.  Git doesn't work that way; you should have based the second version on the first version.

Comment: Is there a quick way to delete all files in remote git repository? So that I will commit the files from Local Copy (2) freshly without deleting the repository.

Comment: @Kartick If you poke around the site, you may find some workarounds (with varying degrees of ugliness).  If you only want to sync a handful of files, you can always pull the remote version, and then just paste in your local copies and commit.